# CSS grid on android loollipop, cordova-ionic not working

Tags: css, cordova, ionic-framework

I am developing an Ionic3 app. I have used CSS grid for layout. Please see emulator inspector screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

```
margin-top: 15px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 33% 33% 33%;
    grid-column-gap: 5px;
    grid-row-gap: 1em;
    width: 100%;
```

This is not working. Please help.

Comment: please describe what exactly not working!

Comment: as Screenshot shows, display:grid is not valid value, all child div are not inheriting grid property and rendered as normal divs

Answer (score 0):

you Have to times "display" set:
    `display: grid`
and than
    `display: flex`
the second one overwrites the first one!